# Spring + hibernate lazy fetching

Tags: hibernate, spring, gwt, lazy-evaluation

I have problem with org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role.

How to implement lazy fetching with gwt + spring + hibernate?

Here's my appContext:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xsi:schemaLocation="   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="sessionFactory"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.yeah.server.*"/>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
    <!--Mysql database connection info-->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.4:3306/YeaH"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>com/yeah/shared/model/User.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/yeah/shared/model/Comment.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/yeah/shared/model/Album.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/yeah/shared/model/Picture.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!--HIbernate session management
 <bean name="openSessionInViewInterceptor"
     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
 <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
 <property name="singleSession" value="false"/>
 </bean>
 -->
    <!-- a PlatformTransactionManager is still required -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: See http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The exception occurs because you're trying to access a lazy loaded property on a domain object after the hibernate session it was loaded in has been closed.

A common way of fixing this is to use the Spring OpenSessonInViewFilter. This essentially scopes your hibernate session to your HTTP request. Then any property access that occurs within that HTTP request/response cycle will be within the scope of that session.

You configure it in your web.xml as follows:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used your code and know I have another problem, maybe you can help
om.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'org.hibernate.collection.PersistentList' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = []  at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:614)

Comment: This doesn't look like a hibernate issue. I'm afraid I've never used GWT. Perhaps a new question would get you an answer.

Comment: Definitely a hibernate + GWT issue. See http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate.html

Comment: has your POJO bean implemented Serializable interface?

Answer (score 0):

generally this type of problem occurs in bidirectional mapping in hibernate ,for this you use @jsonbackrefrence on child side(manytoone) and @jsonmanagedfrence on parent side(onetomany) and must add fetch type EAGER.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with _JSON_.