# How to access lazy hibernate collections from jsp foreach in spring?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I need to do forEach over lazy collection in jsp from spring controller. But this invocation crashes because session was closed in controller. I solve this by loding collection via: 
    `Hibernate.initialize(obj.getCollection())`
Is it possible to tune mvc to have hibernate session inside jsp?

Thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But this invocation crashes because session was closed in controller

I assume by crash you mean that you caused a LazyInitializationException by accessing a mapped collection after the session was closed.

Tuning mvc to have Hibernate session inside you JSP essentially means that you want to hold the session open for the duration of your HTTP request. This means that at render time you can still load the data you require.

You can achieve this using the open session in view pattern. In Spring this is implemented using the OpenSessionInViewFilter. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062413/spring-hibernate-lazy-fetching/6063227#6063227) for more detail on setting it up.

The alternative as you have already demonstrated it to load the data that you require within the transaction which loaded the parent. This is why Hibernate supports lazy loading. Sometimes you will need to load child entities and collections but sometimes you don't. By mapping it as lazy you can choose depending on the specific interaction.

Comment: If you reference complete code sample with OpenSessionInViewPattern, I'll accept your answer. Thanx.

Comment: I've linked to another answer with the required changes. Also this is a question/answer site. Not a site for demanding complete code samples. I've pointed you in the right direction now you need to go and work out how to finish it off. This is not a new question there are literally thousands of people out there who have asked the same thing so I'd guess there must be many 'complete code samples' for people who want to copy and paste.